# symfony 1.4 - redirection in security.yml

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

How to redirect a user to a page depending on the role.

For example:

There is a module hello_world, and it has an action index (it prints the text "Hello World")

There is a module user, and in it there is action userList.

The administrator can view all these actions.
User can only view the hello_world page.

How to do this with security.yml files.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

You can define security credentials for each module. If the user doesn't need a credential, then

`/.../modules/hello_world/config/security.yml`

```
all:
  is_secure: false
```

And

`/.../modules/user/config/security.yml`

```
all:
  is_secure: true
  credentials: [ admin ]
userList:
  credentials: [ SOME_SPECIFIC_CREDENTIALS_FOR_ACTION ]
```